# ASP.Net Ajax AsyncFileUpload events not firing after postback - ASP.NET, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, events, asyncfileupload

I have ASP.Net Ajax AsyncFileUpload in one of my pages. All the events including OnUploadedComplete, are firing fine after page load and after page is posted back using a button or something those events are not firing.

**This is my form tag**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**This is my AsyncFileUpload tag**

```
<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUpload" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientUploadStarted="onClientUploadStarted" OnClientUploadComplete="onClientUploadCompleted" OnClientUploadError="onClientUploadError"
                            Width="100%" UploaderStyle="Traditional" OnUploadedComplete="ProcessUpload" UploadingBackColor="#FFFFFF"
                            ErrorBackColor="White" CompleteBackColor="White" CssClass="upload" Style="display: none" />
```

and I have used a master page in my project.This is weird and any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edited**

In the browser console there is an error saying,

*Uncaught ReferenceError: partialLoad is not defined*

Comment: which peace of code you need King ? my page consists of 2000 lines :)

Comment: c# code of events related to the AsyncFileUpload

Comment: I have OnUploadComplete as c# event and my problem is that event is not firing as I mentioned. I have put a breake point and checked :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the reason why it didn't work. I have called none existing javascript function (Using ScriptManager) in the button click event and that's why console showed that  *Uncaught ReferenceError: partialLoad is not defined*  error. Once I removed that function call, AsyncFileUpload events worked Fine.

Thanks for the quick response **king.code** and **Ronaldinho Learn Coding**

cheers (Y)